# ec2 Alma 9.2 stuck on old kernel version

Tags: grub2, yum, amazon-ec2, dnf, alma-linux

```
# the issue:
dnf check-update
Last metadata expiration check: 1:35:58 ago on Sun Jun  4 10:26:18 2023.
Security: kernel-core-5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2.aarch64 is an installed security update
Security: kernel-core-5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.aarch64 is the currently running version

# double check:
uname -r
5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.aarch64

# only reboot is not fixing it:
uptime
12:01:37 up 0 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.34, 0.10, 0.04

# the cfg is up to date:
grub2-mkconfig > test.cfg 2>/dev/null
diff test.cfg /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

# and manually it looks fine:
. /usr/share/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib 
version_find_latest $(ls -1 /boot/vmlinuz-*)
/boot/vmlinuz-5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2.aarch64

# maybe these efi boot logs are related:
grep -Pi "efi\b" /var/log/messages | tail -n 6
Jun  4 12:00:59 amazon4 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Amazon Elastic Block Store EFI\x20System\x20Partition being skipped.
Jun  4 12:00:59 amazon4 systemd[1]: Mounting /boot/efi...
Jun  4 12:00:59 amazon4 systemd[1]: Mounted /boot/efi.
Jun  4 12:00:59 amazon4 systemd[1]: Store a System Token in an EFI Variable was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/LoaderFeatures-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-440b29bb8c4f).
Jun  4 12:00:59 amazon4 systemd[1]: TPM2 PCR Barrier (Initialization) was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/StubPcrKernelImage-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-440b29bb8c4f).
Jun  4 12:00:59 amazon4 systemd[1]: TPM2 PCR Barrier (User) was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/StubPcrKernelImage-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-440b29bb8c4f).
```

non-efi VMs don't have this issue.

How can grub/efi be told to use the newer kernel?

**Edit 01:**

Thanks to @Svižný_Svišť for sharing

```
grubby --info=ALL
grub2-reboot 1
```

so listing what is installed;

```
dnf list --installed | grep "kernel-core"
kernel-core.aarch64                5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1               @baseos   
kernel-core.aarch64                5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2              @baseos   
kernel-core.aarch64                5.14.0-284.18.1.el9_2              @baseos
```

I removed this one:

```
dnf remove kernel-core-5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1
```

but grubby still listed it, so I fixed it with

```
grubby --remove-kernel=/boot/vmlinuz-5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.aarch64
```

Comment: You are currently using the most recent version of the [Almalinux 9 kernel, kernel-core-5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2](http://repo.almalinux.org/almalinux/9/BaseOS/aarch64/os/Packages/kernel-core-5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2.aarch64.rpm) which was released in May.  Almalinux 9 will likely be using Linux kernel 5.14 for all versions of 9.x.  Which kernel version are you expecting?

Comment: @GracefulRestart dnf clearly states otherwise.

Comment: Could you do `uname -a` on the system?

Comment: @tukan I added that to the Q; dnf is not mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dnf fails to update grub properly, sometimes one must do it manually like so:

```
grubby --remove-kernel=/boot/vmlinuz-5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.aarch64
reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced this issue upgrading from `kernel-core-5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2.x86_64` to `kernel-core-5.14.0-284.18.1.el9_2.x86_64`

Although I have not found a solution, I discovered that setting the "next boot only" default boot entry for GRUB does indeed load the desired kernel:

```
$ sudo grubby --info=ALL | grep -E '^(kernel|index)'
index=0
kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2.x86_64"
index=1
kernel="/boot/vmlinuz-5.14.0-284.18.1.el9_2.x86_64"

$ sudo grub2-reboot 1   # index 1
$ sudo reboot
```

This obviously loads the latest kernel only temporarily. The boot after, it will be back to the previous one. While not intended as a fix, it may give someone else an idea as to where to look next.

Comment: Thanks, after that I think the offending version can just be uninstalled (looking for the syntax for that now...)

Comment: Yes, it could be. I did not suggest that, however, as I like to keep a proven older kernel as a backup in case there is some issue with the latest kernel that I did not detect straight away after the first reboot.